# Using siunitx, how to simultaneously align values by decimal points and in the center in all columns of table?

Tags: tables

I have a table with five columns, containing decimal numbers and powers of 10 and I am trying to use the siunitx package for the formatting. What I would like to have in the end are

1. centered values
2. values aligned by the second decimal point
3. the above two for all five columns.

Here is the code for the table in its current form:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{S|c|c|c|c}
A & B & C & D & E\\
\hline \hline
1.75 & $4.5 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.4 (0.1) \times 10^2$ & $3.4 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.4 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\ 
1.65 & $4.8 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.4 (0.1) \times 10^2$ & $3.0 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.6 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\
1.5 & $5.9 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.8 (0.1) \times 10^2$ & $3.6 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $2.0 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\
1.4 & $6.5 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $1.8 (0.1) \times 10^2$ & $4.4 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $1.7 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\
1.25 & $8.0 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $2.7 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $5.1 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $2.0 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\
1.1 & $10.4 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $2.9 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $6.2 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $2.6 (0.1) \times 10^2$ \\
0.95 & $14.0 (0.4) \times 10^2$ & $3.5 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $9.4 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $3.3 (0.2) \times 10^2$ \\
0.8 & $18.2 (0.4) \times 10^2$ & $4.3 (0.2) \times 10^2$ & $12.2 (0.4) \times 10^2$ & $4.1 (0.2) \times 10^2$ \\
0.65 & $27.3 (0.5) \times 10^2$ & $7.4 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $19.7 (0.4) \times 10^2$ & $5.6 (0.2) \times 10^2$ \\
0.5 & $44.5 (0.7) \times 10^2$ & $11.5 (0.3) \times 10^2$ & $30.9 (0.6) \times 10^2$ & $8.1 (0.3) \times 10^2$\\
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{width = 0.7\linewidth}
\caption{Observed count rates for each radioactive source measured at various distances. Contained in parentheses are the corresponding Poisson distribution errors.}
\label{tab:ObsCount}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: In my humble opinion, the powers on ten should be moved to tabular headers.

Comment: the image is clearly not generated by the code shown.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make effective use of the machinery of the `siunitx` package, I suggest you express the uncertainty amounts as single-digit entities; say, as `(2)` instead of as `(0.2)`. This'll give you the freedom of specifying the option `separate-uncertainty` if and when needed (or desired); see the second table belows.

A separate suggestion: I suggest you encase both the `tabular` environment and the `\caption` directive in a `threeparttable` environment; that way, LaTeX will automatically limit the width of the caption string to that of the associated `tabular` environment. I'd also get rid of all vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=1.2]
   *{4}{S[table-format=2.1(1)e1]} 
   @{}}
{A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} \\
\midrule
1.75 &  4.5(2)e2 &  1.4(1)e2 &  3.4(2)e2 & 1.4(1)e2 \\ 
1.65 &  4.8(2)e2 &  1.4(1)e2 &  3.0(2)e2 & 1.6(1)e2 \\
1.5  &  5.9(2)e2 &  1.8(1)e2 &  3.6(2)e2 & 2.0(1)e2 \\
1.4  &  6.5(3)e2 &  1.8(1)e2 &  4.4(2)e2 & 1.7(1)e2 \\
1.25 &  8.0(3)e2 &  2.7(2)e2 &  5.1(2)e2 & 2.0(1)e2 \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Observed count rates for each radioactive source measured at various distances. Contained in parentheses are the corresponding Poisson distribution errors.}
\label{tab:ObsCountX}
\end{threeparttable}

\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=1.2]
   *{4}{S[table-format=2.1(1)e1,separate-uncertainty]} 
   @{}}
{A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} \\
\midrule
1.1  & 10.4(3)e2 &  2.9(2)e2 &  6.2(3)e2 & 2.6(1)e2 \\
0.95 & 14.0(4)e2 &  3.5(2)e2 &  9.4(3)e2 & 3.3(2)e2 \\
0.8  & 18.2(4)e2 &  4.3(2)e2 & 12.2(4)e2 & 4.1(2)e2 \\
0.65 & 27.3(5)e2 &  7.4(3)e2 & 19.7(4)e2 & 5.6(2)e2 \\
0.5  & 44.5(7)e2 & 11.5(3)e2 & 30.9(6)e2 & 8.1(3)e2 \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Observed count rates for each radioactive source measured at various distances. Contained in parentheses are the corresponding Poisson distribution errors.}
\label{tab:ObsCountX}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

## First solution: 2 cols per value

You can use `@` in tabular definition: it sets the column separator. with `$r @{$\times$} l$` you can use two columns for each value; the first for the number, the second for the power of ten.

## Edit : 3 cols per value

You can do even better with `>{...}` and `<{...}` which add contents before and after a column. For example, `>{$} c <{$}` is a centered column in math mode.

Then, use 3 columns for each value:

1. The first for the number, right-aligned in math mode: `>{$} r <{$}`.
2. The second for the uncertainty, surrounded by  braces in math mode: `>{$(} c <{)$}`.
3. The third for to power of ten, left-aligned: `>{$\times 10\expandafter^\bgroup} l <{\egroup$}`. Here `\bgroup` and `\egroup`  mean `{` and `}`, and an `\expandafter` trick is needed to put the content of the columns in superscript.

With theses definitions, no need of `$` in the tabular. Remove with `@{}` the separation between columns.

Note that if needed, new columns types can be defined:

```tex
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$} r <{$}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{$(} c <{)$}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{$\times 10\expandafter^\bgroup} l <{\egroup$}}
```

Full code:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}
    {
      S *{4}{
        >{$} r <{$} @{}                                   % number
        >{$(} c <{)$} @{}                                 % uncertainty
        >{$\times 10\expandafter^\bgroup} l <{\egroup$}   % power of ten
      }
    }
    \toprule
    A                     &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{E} \\
    \midrule
    1.75 & 4.5  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.4  & 0.1 & 2 & 3.4  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.4 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    1.65 & 4.8  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.4  & 0.1 & 2 & 3.0  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.6 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    1.5  & 5.9  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.8  & 0.1 & 2 & 3.6  & 0.2 & 2 & 2.0 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    1.4  & 6.5  & 0.3 & 2 & 1.8  & 0.1 & 2 & 4.4  & 0.2 & 2 & 1.7 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    1.25 & 8.0  & 0.3 & 2 & 2.7  & 0.2 & 2 & 5.1  & 0.2 & 2 & 2.0 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    1.1  & 10.4 & 0.3 & 2 & 2.9  & 0.2 & 2 & 6.2  & 0.3 & 2 & 2.6 & 0.1 & 2 \\
    0.95 & 14.0 & 0.4 & 2 & 3.5  & 0.2 & 2 & 9.4  & 0.3 & 2 & 3.3 & 0.2 & 2 \\
    0.8  & 18.2 & 0.4 & 2 & 4.3  & 0.2 & 2 & 12.2 & 0.4 & 2 & 4.1 & 0.2 & 2 \\
    0.65 & 27.3 & 0.5 & 2 & 7.4  & 0.3 & 2 & 19.7 & 0.4 & 2 & 5.6 & 0.2 & 2 \\
    0.5  & 44.5 & 0.7 & 2 & 11.5 & 0.3 & 2 & 30.9 & 0.6 & 2 & 8.1 & 0.3 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Observed count rates for each radioactive source measured at various
    distances. Contained in parentheses are the corresponding Poisson
    distribution errors.}
  \label{tab:ObsCount}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular with alignment]

Comment: In the first sentence of your answer, you suggest using `@{$\times$}`, but in the answer code you use `@{\times}`; please fix. And should the second instance of `\toprule` maybe be `\bottomrule`? A separate suggestion: You could get rid of all 160 [!] or so `$` symbols inside the `tabular` environment by switching to an `array` environment. E.g., `$\begin{array}{ S *{4}{r @{{}\times{}} l} }` ... `\end{array}$`.

Comment: @Mico My apologies, I didn't check enough. Curiously, `lualatex` didn't complain, while `pdflatex` does. Fixed. I'll look at your `array` suggestion. Thanks.